# Not able to connect to internet when both ethernet and wifi is connected in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I have `Ubuntu 16.04` (machine 1) and `Windows 10` (machine2). I have connected the ubuntu to the wifi with IP `192.168.0.110` and I can browse internet easily.

I have to do remote `C++` development on ubuntu from windows using Visual studio. I have connected the Ethernet cable between ubuntu and windows. On both the side I have set  the static IP i.e. ubuntu has `192.168.0.150` and windows has `192.168.0.149`. I can ping windows from ubuntu and vice versa. But when I try to browse internet on Ubuntu, its not working. If I disconnect wired connection from ubuntu, I can browse the internet fine. I don't know what I have done wrong here due to which I am not able to connect to internet on Ubuntu.

Can anyone please suggest any idea. Thanks

Comment: Is this a cross cable connection between the two systems or a connection to the same network (router) as the Wifi?

Comment: I didnt get you but looks like its connection to same network. Do I need to modify the IP to some other range like `192.168.1.xx` instead of `192.168.0.xx`.?

Answer (score 1):

Likely a problem of routing. When you connect the Ethernet, Network manager assumes that it also connects to the Internet and since it has a higher priority (or smaller "metrics"), or is just assumed faster, it routes all the traffic through it.

Possible fixes:

- Use the connection manager to declare the Ethernet connection to have a lower priority (which may mean a higher number)
- Reset the default routing after connecting the Ethernet: `ip route ...`. You maye have to set a specific routing for the Windows machine.
- Don't use Ethernet on Ubuntu. Just connect the Windows system to the same LAN (Wifi or Ethernet to the router) and use its LAN address on the Ubuntu side.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the wired connection settings:
In the IP4 menu
Select shared to other computers
https://www.tecmint.com/share-internet-in-linux/